# Shouldn't downvoting uninteresting posts be forbidden?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

In connection with the question: [Is it OK to downvote a question for being uninteresting?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/is-it-ok-to-downvote-a-question-for-being-uninteresting) So if you want to mark this post as duplicate, **analyze** my question and the link I have given first before flagging this post.

<sub>**Let me make it clear that I din't stated the quotations below. They came from the link I have given above. The reason why I included them is because they caught my attention, and it seems like it is not just me who thinks this site practices unfair voting.**</sub>

I have read in this question that you can downvote a post that **if you think it is uninteresting**. In proportion to Help Centre:

> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community
>   that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting
>   down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong
>   information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate
>   information.

However, this can cause several disadvantages. I will state three of my points.

### Unrightful Way.

> I'm not sure I agree that this is a necessarily implication. For example, if an employee does very well, I may give them a bonus. But the proper response to an employee performing poorly is generally not to deduct money from their salary.

This is actually right. I don't think it is necessary to downvote a question just because you think it is uninteresting. How about for the others? Of course, anyone who posted a question and when someone downvoted it for being **an uninteresting question**, the user will be displeased.

### Anti-Social Behavior.

> Well, I'm not one to go starting arguments on the Interwebs, but I think that downvoting a post because you don't find it interesting is a destructive, evil, morally reprehensible, anti-intellectual, self-centered, close-minded, anti-social behavior that should be disallowed.

I think the comment states it all.

### Unfair Voting

> I have trouble with the fact that you admit you "wouldn't have time" to downvote all the questions that apparently bore you but "sometimes" you go ahead and make such downvotes. If you can't apply something consistently, it might be better not to do it all. Beyond this, I struggle to see the value of downvoting in anything other than especially egregious cases. More often than not, refraining from upvoting sends the same message as downvoting but without the negativity and trauma.

It's actually politely RIGHT. If you want to downvote a question just because it's boring, shouldn't you downvote every question you find uninteresting?

**NOTE:** It isn't wrong to downvote. I just don't find it necessary to downvote a question for being **uninteresting**. Every user here cares for his/her reputation. I think downvoting should only be for those questions that are *unrelated, broad, etc.* But if someone posts a question and a user finds it uninteresting, it should just be left alone. Maybe for some it is uninteresting, but what if others might actually enjoy it? Especially for the newbies. Please take note that this is not a rant. I'm just stating how unlawful this kind of rule is.

Comment: Please take note that this is not a rant. I'm just stating how unlawful this kind of rule is.

Comment: Can you provide a link to some questions where you feel that you were downvoted for being uninteresting?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173389/why-does-the-goblet-in-the-cave-constantly-empties I really don't know as to why this was downvoted by 4 users.

Comment: Oh, I can tell you that. I downvoted it because I didn't think it was an especially good question. The answer seems obvious, and like... really? I downvoted it not because it was uninteresting, but because I found it to be a poor question. I don't mean to offend you, and I apologize if I have. I'm just trying to explain why I downvoted.

Comment: @Mithrandir I don't think the answers seems to be pretty obvious. It's ok, atleast you explained. I actually didn't posted this question just for myself, I found a lot of questions dropping their scores to negative just because some found it uninteresting, and I don't think it's a fair rule for this site.

Comment: Your employee analogy honestly doesn't really make much sense at all and seems rather unconnected to the problem you're describing. But *if* you really want to go down that road, please note that constantly underperforming in the business world is not without consequences either, from, yes, *paycuts* upto, well, dropping him from being an employee at all.

Comment: The main reason is that in an anonymous voting system it's impossible to force people to only vote for a specific set of acceptable reasons.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a rant. If you want to ask why a *particular* question was downvoted, then ask about that question, not the voting system in general.

Comment: You know what annoys me, the question is downvoted ,but the answer is upvoted. Without the question there would be no answer to upvote.

Comment: Honestly, your comments are off-topic. You haven't even answered my question. Not one of those comments even managed to subvert this question. What I hate in this site is that people tell to me I'm full of **rants**. While in the other sites, people leave the questions they think are boring. Unlike here, you post need to score down first, and then find a good place at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Valorum Before commenting on this post, **try to understand my post first**. The comments I have given above which are typed with **blockquote** are not my comments. These comments came from the link I have given and they caught my attention. That's why the comments are in a **blockquote**. I don't think it'll be put there without a purpose? It seems like it is not just me who thinks this site is fulled of liabilities. Of course, no one would listen to my post. Because whoever runs this site might not even listen to my opinion, might as well downvote this post. Do what you want.

Comment: @Invoker As per SE police (not in discussion) you can downvote for any reason. About if it's ok or no to be encouraged, opinions in the question you cited seem  fifty-fifty. But about your question, how do you expect to forbid someone from downvoting because it's uninteresting? How would you even know the intention behind the downvote? Without intending to offend you, that's why this questions feels like a rant because it can not accomplish any meaningful disccussion (ofc you can post an answer in the original question or vote there).

Comment: @Invoker - If you want to fundamentally change how the site works, you'll need to go the [main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and ask there.

Answer (score 9):

There are two underlying premises about voting on SE that you need to keep in mind:

The first is that in a crowd-based system (like voting on SE), it's the *aggregate* and *relative* results that are useful, not individual votes.

If a "lot" of people vote on a "lot" of posts (questions and answers) then - in general - "good" posts will end up with higher votes than "bad" posts.

The second is that votes on a question or answer are not primarily intended to give feedback to the person who made the post.  Votes are meant to tell *other people* what the community thinks about a question or answer.

So, looking at your 3 points:

> anyone who posted a question and when someone downvoted it for being an uninteresting question, the user will be displeased.

That may be true, but votes aren't primarily for the person who posted.

> ... I think that downvoting a post because you don't find it interesting is a destructive, evil, morally reprehensible, anti-intellectual, self-centered, close-minded, anti-social behavior that should be disallowed.

Agreeing with this comment actually makes your post a rant, because it's *waaaaaay* over the top....  In what way is it destructive to downvote? (for whatever reason) Or morally reprehensible?

> If you want to downvote a question just because it's boring, shouldn't you downvote every question you find uninteresting?

I find this viewpoint just as over-the-top as the one about it being evil to downvote...  Think it through: If you really think everyone should be required to vote consistently, then you're saying everyone who votes at all should have to read and vote on every single post.

Again, voting is meaningful when a lot of people do it, so if I don't read and/or don't vote on every post, it's not a problem because other people will get them.

> Maybe for some it is uninteresting, but what if others might actually enjoy it? Especially for the newbies.

If others enjoy it, then they're free to vote it up.  As long as enough people vote, the overall score will be a reflection of how much the community likes or doesn't like the question or answer.

Finally, you should keep in mind that you unless someone says in a comment "I downvoted this because I found it uninteresting," you have no way of knowing if that's the reason.  I would think that in many cases, "uninteresting" is just another way of saying "unclear" or "not useful" or "not researched," all of which are explicitly listed as valid reasons to downvote.

Comment: Let me make this clear. These are not my comments. They came from the page I linked in this question. And I have just given my insights to these comments. Isn't it clear that it's in a quotation statement? And I'm not pertaining this post to my posts. I'm actually pertaining this to all users, especially the newbies.

Comment: *votes are meant to tell other people what the community thinks about a question or answer.*      so how about the other votes? Should we just disregard them? And **uninteresting** is way different from **unclear** and **not useful**.

Comment: I know it's a quote, but you included it as one of your 3 points, so you are clearly agreeing with it.  I'm not sure what "other votes" you're referring to in your second comment.